# data-client-key inside script tag on React

Tags: reactjs

I do some research about set script on react like this example:

```
componentDidMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "https://www.example.com/example.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

I need to set `data-client-key` inside it but seems like react failed to compile it. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: why do you need to? from what product of google is this? Which line of code is in ..google.js that requires data-client-key?

Comment: because if it's google's map api, then just append the key to the url: `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: no its not google js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setAttribute

```
script.setAttribute('data-client-key', 'Your Key')?
```

Your componentDidMount will look like

```
 componentDidMount() {
    let s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "https://google.com";
    s.setAttribute("data-some-thing", 12);
    document.body.appendChild(s);
 }
```